# How scalable is open source parse server?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, web-hosting

I've read in several places, (some in stackoverflow) Parse is not that suitable when it comes to large scale applications. Imagine an instagram like application with very high concurrent access.

However, Parse server is now open source and we can host it anywhere (AWS etc.) Does that make any difference? Is it suitable for large scale applications now? Or is it the technology that's been used to develop Parse bottlenecking the scalability (not the servers) ?

**EDIT: All the limitations of parse**
http://profi.co/all-the-limits-of-parse/